# Azure VM Run PowerShell Script doesn't Output

Tags: python, azure, powershell, azure-runbook, azure-vm

I'm attempting to run a python script inside of my Windows 10 Azure VM. I've managed to connect to the VM and run the script from an Automation runbook but nothing from the powershell script seems to be outputted after the runbook completes.

My python script stored at `C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.py`:

```
print("Hello World.")
```

My powershell script stored at `C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.ps1`:

```
Write-Output "Starting Script..."
C:\Users\username\Python\python.exe C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.py
Write-Output "Shutting Down..."
```

My Azure runbook named VMRunTest:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$rgname ="ParcelTracking"
$vmname ="ParcelTracking-Scraper"
$ScriptToRun = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.ps1"
Out-File -InputObject $ScriptToRun -FilePath ScriptToRun.ps1 
Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $vmname -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath ScriptToRun.ps1
Remove-Item -Path ScriptToRun.ps1
```

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#:%7E:text=Run%20Command%20can%20run%20scripts,script%20within%20a%20virtual%20machine.) it also requires that I open the output port on the VM to allow the `443` port with the `AzureCloud` tag. In the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMGc2.png) you what my setting are for that.

When I execute the Azure Runbook, I get no errors, warnings, and no exceptions. This is the output that follows:

```
Logging in to Azure...


Environments                                                                                                            
------------                                                                                                            
{[AzureChinaCloud, AzureChinaCloud], [AzureCloud, AzureCloud], [AzureGermanCloud, AzureGermanCloud], [AzureUSGovernme...


Value     : {Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.InstanceViewStatus, 
            Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.InstanceViewStatus}
Name      : 
StartTime : 
EndTime   : 
Status    : Succeeded
Error     : 
Output    : 
Capacity  : 0
Count     : 0
Item      :
```

So, it appears to have been successful, however I don't see any mention of the `Hello World.` statement or either output statements from the powershell script. So, I can only assume that the python script is not executing. I also know this from trying this process on a python script that should take roughly ~15minutes to run and it comes back as completed within 1 minute.

I think I'm close, just missing a few minor details somewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you run the script from the PowerShell can you check if it spawns a new shell and then executes your script? If that is the case it may not show it as the execution is happening of another shell and you are not taking the output of that execution and printing is explicitly.

Comment: When I run the powershell script from within the VM, I get the outputs that I am expecting. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: In addition, when I copy the contents of the powershell script into the Azure "Run Command" operation from the VM page, it also is able to output the following: ```Starting Script...
Hello World.
Shutting Down...```

Comment: Is there any permission that you have to add to execute it remotely.

Comment: I don't think so (but ultimately don't know the correct answer). I believe most of the permissions get taken care of within the runbook. I assumed that if it could successfully connect to the VM, that it could successfully execute the `Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand` command.

Comment: I don't know the solution I can give you some pointers to check. 
1. Is your python script able to access files it need? 
2. Check is the python path is correct?
3. Is there any way you can put more debug logs when this is executing like try to execute and if error catch and show the error. 
These are a few points that you can check, don't have much idea of windows env.

Comment: Since the python script only prints: "Hello World." and nothing else, I know that #1 is not the issue. I have also checked and ensured that the python path is correct. As far as #3, are you recommending this be done within the runbook or somewhere else?

Comment: `Out-File -InputObject $ScriptToRun -FilePath ScriptToRun.ps1` the output of `$ScriptToRun` will be "C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.ps1" try `Out-File -InputObject $(& $ScriptToRun) -FilePath ScriptToRun.ps1`

Comment: @AustinUlfers Please login your vm and check the extension log. The log path is `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#troubleshoot`. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#troubleshoot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, actually it works.

Change the line

```
Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $vmname -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath ScriptToRun.ps1
```

to

```
$run = Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $vmname -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath ScriptToRun.ps1 
Write-Output $run.Value[0]
```

Then you will be able to see the output(in my vm, I didn't install python, for a quick test, I just use powershell, in your case, it should also work).

[image]

Comment: This may deserve to be a new question, but this solution prints the results once the script has finished executing. Is there a way to change this so that as new info is printed from the script, that gets automatically printed to the runbook on Azure's side while the script is still running?